# Heroku Python Django App Deployment Failure: No module named 'oauth2_provider'

Tags: python, django, heroku, oauth-2.0

I am following the [Django OAuth Toolkit tutorial](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html).  I have the app running successfully on my local server with Django OAuth Toolkit installed.

When I try to deploy to Heroku I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2_provider'" error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

I have attempted to search Stack Overflow for similar questions but was unable to find one.  I saw many questions on Stack Overflow relating to collectstatic but I do not think that is my problem.

My backtrace is as so:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2_provider'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
```

My settings.py Installed Apps is as so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Disable Django's own staticfiles handling in favour of WhiteNoise, for
    # greater consistency between gunicorn and `./manage.py runserver`. See:
    # http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

I am using Python 3.6.1 and my requirements.txt is as so:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.11.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
whitenoise==3.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing this package in your `requirements.txt` file. So add `django-oauth-toolkit` there and it should work

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman sir!  THANK YOU @mateuszb.  This did the trick.  For anyone else having this problem I also had to add django-cors-middleware to my requirements file as well.  I am a django noob and I am not exactly sure why it would work locally without these lines in the requirements.txt file but when I push to heroku they are required.  Hmm.

Comment: @GW1732 It was working because you had both packages already installed in your system ;) When you're using another environment (e.g. Heroku), you have to explicitly specify which packages are required to install ;)

Comment: Aha.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the package "django-oauth-toolkit", execute:

```
pip install -U django-oauth-toolkit
```

or

```
pip3 install -U django-oauth-toolkit
```

Another fix could be upgrade your python version, I got this problem with python 2.7, but not with python 3.5