# How do I update my Heroku app without "Application Error"

Tags: heroku

This is the result when I open the app in heroku after doing an update.

Application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

This was the procedure I did when doing the updates:

```
heroku login
heroku info
heroku git:remote --app tcwhais
git add .
git commit -m "first update"
git heroku push master
heroku open
```

Because the web did not open, I did the following:
I installed the Heroku CLI (64-bit)

```
heroku login
heroku git:clone -a tcwhais
cd tcwhais
git add .
git commit -am"to correct error"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

This is the logs of the updates:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\mysite\INO_TCWHAIS> heroku open
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\mysite\INO_TCWHAIS> heroku logs --tail
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573596+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573598+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573600+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573602+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573605+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573607+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573610+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573614+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573616+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573618+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573622+00:00 app[web.1]: import script1
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573624+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/script1.py", line 145, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573625+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2019-11-12T03:06:57.573627+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2019-11-12T03:06:57.574274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:06:57 +0800] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:06:57 +0800] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582460+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582463+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582466+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582470+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582472+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582476+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582478+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582480+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582482+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582484+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582486+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582488+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582489+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582491+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582493+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582495+00:00 app[web.1]: import script1
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582497+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/script1.py", line 145, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582499+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2019-11-12T03:06:57.582506+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2019-11-12T03:06:57.583535+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:06:57 +0800] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-11-12T03:06:57.817914+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:06:57 +0800] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-11-12T03:06:57.818030+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:06:57 +0800] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-11-12T03:06:57.911942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-11-12T03:06:57.915850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-12T03:06:57.888899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-11-12T03:07:06.422412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2019-11-12T03:07:09.884688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-11-12T03:07:09.434491+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:09 +0800] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-11-12T03:07:09.435332+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:09 +0800] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:13556 (4)
2019-11-12T03:07:09.435513+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:09 +0800] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-11-12T03:07:09.440985+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:09 +0800] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-11-12T03:07:09.470380+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:09 +0800] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486361+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486392+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486396+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486399+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486401+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486403+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486452+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsg
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486452+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486458+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486460+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486462+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486464+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486467+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486471+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)

2019-11-12T03:07:16.486473+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486475+00:00 app[web.1]: import script1
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/script1.py", line 145, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486479+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2019-11-12T03:07:16.486491+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2019-11-12T03:07:16.487443+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512372+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512383+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512385+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512388+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512390+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512392+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512394+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512396+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512399+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512401+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512404+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512406+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512408+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512410+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512412+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512414+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512416+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 7, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512418+00:00 app[web.1]: import script1
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512420+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/script1.py", line 145, in <module>
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512423+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2019-11-12T03:07:16.512434+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2019-11-12T03:07:16.513594+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-11-12T03:07:16.819875+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-11-12T03:07:16.820089+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-12 11:07:16 +0800] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-11-12T03:07:16.959707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-11-12T03:07:16.939371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'"—well, have you included `requests` in your dependencies file (either `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`+`Pipfile.lock`)?

Comment: Yah I forgot to add the requests in the requirements.txt. Now it is already working. But a while ago it encountered an error which says "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." This is my application tcwhais.herokuapp.com.

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. This isn't a discussion forum, so please don't ask new questions in the comments. Instead, search for existing questions and if you still have a question post a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Python Django App Deployment Failure: No module named 'oauth2\_provider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422226/heroku-python-django-app-deployment-failure-no-module-named-oauth2-provider)